# HTTPUrl connection closed automatically

Tags: java, url, jaxb

i am reading a xml response using httpurlconnection. i parsed the response using JAXB. I didnt close the connection. When i again try to read from the URL , I am getting the error as Input stream. Do i have to open connection twice or is there any way to open connection once and read the response twice and then close the connection?

Answer (score 0):

JAXB likely consumes the `InputStream` and then closes it. You would need to use some kind of [`FilterInputStream`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/FilterInputStream.html) so that it's buffered and reusable.

With `Guava`, you can do something like

```
HttpURLConnection con = ...; // get it
InputStream in = con.getInputStream();
String content = CharStreams.toString(new InputStreamReader(in, Charsets.UTF_8));
```

Then pass a new `InputStream` to JAXB made from the bytes of `content`.

```
InputStream inForJAXB = new ByteArrayInputStream(content.getBytes());
```

You can do the same thing again for any other component that needs the content of the `HttpURLConnection` input stream.